# JavaFX HTMLEditor: HTML to plain text

Tags: java, html, javafx

I know that you can use HTMLEditor.getHTMLText(); to convert text to HTML, I was just wondering if you can **convert the HTML text back to plain text**.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with "convert the HTML text back to html"?

Comment: Ehh... awkward mistake thanks a lot, I ment to say convent the HTML text back to plain text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is to remove all the HTML tags from the HTML String returned by [`getHtmlText`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/HTMLEditor.html#getHtmlText--).

You can implement a method, or better, you can use for example [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) to do the job for you:

```
Jsoup.parse(htmlText).text();
```

**Example**

```
HTMLEditor editor = new HTMLEditor();
Button b = new Button("Get Text");
b.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(editor.getHtmlText()).text()));
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to test it out.